# import product images via csv in magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9

I have already imported simple and configurable products. Now I need to import multiple images for a product. I need csv format and process to upload images.

Answer (score 0):

This is the format of your CSV file
`sku,image
sku1,/sku1/sample1.jpg
sku1,/sku1/sample2.jpg
sku1,/sku1/sample3.jpg
sku2,/sku2/sample21.jpg
sku2,/sku2/sample22.jpg
sku2,/sku2/sample23.jpg`

Please make sure images are placed at this folder
`media/import`

And now you can import product images using import all products data flow profiles

you can refer here for more detail of [importing images for magento products](https://blog.beehexa.com/2016/10/23/magento-1-image-does-not-exist-when-importing-products/)

Comment: @rksoni - would you like to approve this as correct answer?